# Laravel Authorization Different Table

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I am creating an API for requests. I have a different table for the authentication, so I have changed the table to physiotherapists instead of users like so:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'physiotherapists',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'physiotherapists' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Physiotherapist::class,
]
```

I looked at other solutions for API authentication and found this: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

I copied the login, register and details functions. But here comes my problem... It seems like

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
```

does not correctly authenticate my physiotherapists table. The physiotherapists table also has a email and password column.

Somehow when I send the correct information to it from the users table it also doesn't work.

Could anybody help me fix this problem?

Edit: Physiotherapist that extends authenticable just like User does.

```
class Physiotherapist extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

  public function patients() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Patient');
  } 
}
```

Comment: if(Auth:::guard('api')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I use that (there is 1 : too much), it gives me this error:

    Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.

Comment: what is your route?

Comment: Route::POST('user_token', 'LoginController@login'); (in api.php)

Comment: Auth::routes(''user_token', 'LoginController@login'); try this

Comment: Also put it in api.php

Comment: Did that, still got an unauthorized response back from the API. Seems like it's still not doing the right thing at Auth:attempt

Comment: plz check are you getting email and password in your function??

Comment: Yes. I am getting the email in request('email') and the password in request('password'). I will update my post to show my controller for the physiotherapist btw.

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

Comment: add this in your model

Comment: I do not have a remember_token for the Physiotherapists table, can I remove that?

Comment: Added that, still  no luck (without the remember_token).